# Modifying HEVC HM reference codec

Tags: visual-studio-2010, video, hevc, h.265

I'm very new to the field of HEVC codec. I'm using the HM reference code version 10.1. My task is to make block size up to 128x128. So, what I tried was in the configuration file I set the parameters `MaxCUWidth`, `MaxCUHeight` as 128 and 128 respectively.

This ensures that the max CU size is limited to 128 x 128. However, the code crashes with the errors:

> Error: Minimum CU width must be greater than minimum transform size
>   Error: Minimum CU Height must be greater than minimum transform size

My problem is I'm not able to figure out where & how the code needs to be changed so that it does not effect other parameters. Any Kind of help regarding the same will be really valuable to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum CU width/height is derived from the `MaxCUWidth`/`MaxCUHeight` and the `MaxPartitionDepth` parameters. `MaxPartitionDepth` proscribes, how often a CTU can be splitted. So if you also increase `MaxPartitionDepth` by 1, it should work.

Alternatively, you can increase the parameter `QuadtreeTULog2MinSize` by 1, in order to increase the minimum transform size, but i would recommend the first approach, as this only increases the CTU size, without changing the rest of the configuration.

Comment: I have made changes accordingly but didn't get my answer because i need to get larger block size (Dimensions) 128x128 but it give me error about making changes for above mention approaches.

Comment: error is "QuadtreeTULog2MinSize" must be equal or greater then 2

Comment: What did you enter for "QuadtreeTULog2MinSize" then? Default should be 2, for 4x4 TUs.

Comment: i enter "QuadtreeTULog2MinSize= 2" while "QuadtreeTULog2MaxSize= 6" so then after getting error i change like this "QuadtreeTULog2MinSize= 1" and "QuadtreeTULog2MaxSize= 5" but still got error

Comment: Hm, that's strange. With `MaxCUWidth` and `MaxCUHeight` = 128, `MaxPartitionDepth` = 5, and `QuadtreeTULog2MinSize` = 2, it should be fine. `QuadtreeTULog2MaxSize` must not be greater than 5, so you should keep it at 5. If it doesn't work, you should debug through the member function `xCheckParameter` of `TAppEncCfg`, where the parameters are checked for validity.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me its done now For HEVC HM version (10.1) needs to modify on only Depth increment of 1 while `CusizeWidth` and `CuSizeheight` must be equal to 128. For that purpose I had made changes in `log2Bliksize<=7` containing

> TComPattern.cpp

and made changes in `MAX_CU_DEPTH` in

> TComRom.h

After that i got Block sizes / CU (Dimensions) of 128x128.